# REQL update property of nth element of array

Tags: arrays, updates, rethinkdb

I have following query -

```
r.db("schema").table("table")
  .get("7201f732-4396-4201-9df4-099506a473b5")("observation")("items")(0)
```

which returns following result -

```
{
"description": null ,
"index":  "AF"
"name":  "ALL FARM BASE" ,
"opted": true ,
"parent": null ,
"properties": [
"AF 1" ,
"AF 2"
] ,
"sub_heads": [
"CB" ,
"AB" ,
"LB"
] ,
"type":  "HEAD"
}
```

The query should be enough to explain data structure, but I will explain it any ways. The query basically fetches first of element of array `items`, which is a property of object `observation` of the selected document.

Now how do I update `description` key of above query?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indeed tricky... Something like this:

```
r.db("schema").table("table").get("7201f732-4396-4201-9df4-099506a473b5").update({
  observations: {
    items: r.row('observations')('items').changeAt(
      0,
      r.row('observations')('items')(0).merge({
        description: 'my new description'
      }))
  }
})
```

The query should be enough to explain the process, but I will explain anyways. ;)

- `.get("7201f732-4396-4201-9df4-099506a473b5")` provides the selection we'll be working on
- `.update(...)` will run its argument on each document in the selection, merge the previous document with the result ("merge" here means it's no need to provide the full object, like when using `.replace(...)`), and finally commit the changes to the DB
- `{ observations: { items: ... } }` targets where we're going to work in the document, which keys we're going to alter (here only one, `observations.items`) - it's lossless (object-wise) because we're updating, not replacing
- `r.row('observations')('items')` targets the same point in the document (`r.row` being "the currently processed document" in a selection-processing context), but here we're wrapped in ReQL capabilities, not just using a plain object
- `.changeAt(...)` will alter the array it's called upon, overwriting the index given by its first argument with data provided by its second argument, and returning (not commiting) the new array
- `r.row('observations')('items')(0)` like earlier, but now walking into the first element of the `observations.items` array
- `.merge(...)` merges the object it's called upon with its argument, returning (not commiting) the new value

In English: *get* the specified document, *update* it with the specified array *changed at* the specified index, the new value being the old one *merged* with the specified `description`.